# Backing up multiple git repos of the same project (deduplication)

Tags: backup, git, deduplication

I use a central git server (a gitlab instance). Developers clone projects to a samba share on another server. At the moment, I make backups of the gitlab server and all of the developers directorys on the other server. This costs a lot of disk space. Ideally, I would like to only backup the gitlab server. I can't do that because changes not yet pushed to it could be lost (and I cannot shift responsibility for backups to the developers, e.g. forcing them to push everything once a day). Is there a solution to deduplicate this data with git? I'm not sure if using another deduplication system before the actual backup would work as I think even small changes in a repo could be big for another system when git packfiles change.

Comment: Which backup software are you currently using?  I believe a number of the heavy-weight ones supports at least file level de-duplication, so the only files that would be duplicated are ones that have current edits in them (but the entire repositories wouldn't take up much additional space).

Comment: I use bacula. What I'm worried about are the garbage collected blobs. When all the blobs are packed together in packfiles and you add/change something, the packfiles will change, right? So from the outside (of git) it will seems as a big file that changed so it's backed up completely.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you back up. If you use git for backing up, then it's easy: add a remote for each of the developers' repos and `git fetch` them all. Git then does the deduplication for you by storing each object only once, no matter how many remotes have it.

Comment: Great, now how do you do a restore?

Comment: All the refs (branches) are there, so you simply clone the backup and check out your branches.

Comment: I just don't consider any backup strategy complete without a restore strategy - and tests. :)

Comment: Very good point!

Comment: This might be a good idea. I will need to write some scripts to detect new projects etc. but I think that might work. Thank you.

Comment: I came up with http://pastebin.com/xVPyJ0Ki and will monitor if that does everything I want.